# Subsetting elements in list a based on elements list b

Tags: r, plyr

I have 2 lists:

```
c1 <- c("e","f","g","h")
c2 <- c("j","k","l","m")
list1 <- list(c1,c2)
i1 <- c(1,3)
i2 <- c(2,4)
list2 <- list(i1,i2)
```

I would like to subset the character vectors in list a based on integer vectors in list b. This way I would end up with a new list (list3) containing c1 (with only e and g) and c2 (with only k and m). I'm currently looking into the possibilities of plyr so the solution should preferably be with plyr. I tried something similar to this but to no avail.

```
list3 <- llply(list1, function (x) x[list2])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with `base R` using `Map`, which would be more compact than the one with `llply`.  Basically, you have two lists with same number of list elements and wanted to subset one each list element of the first list ("list1") based on the index list elements of ("list2").  `Map` will compare the corresponding elements of "list1" and "list2" and subset using `[`

```
Map(`[`, list1, list2)
```

which is the same as

```
Map(function(x,y) x[y], list1, list2)
```

Or using `llply` from `plyr` (you don't really need `llply`).  This could be achieved with `lapply` itself.  The key is to compare the corresponding elements of both lists and the possible way you can link both (when they have same elements) is to use `seq_along` which will get you the sequence of elements in one list (`1:3`) and use that index to get the corresponding elements of both list and then subset.

```
llply(seq_along(list1), function(i) list1[[i]][list2[[i]]])
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions are exactly what I was looking for. Would you care to explain how the second solution works? Seq_along(list1) returns an integer vector and I don't understand how you get to the final solution from there.